# weblogic work manager in clustered environment

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

I have created a custom work manager, targeting to a weblogic cluster consisting 4 managed servers.  Assuming that the work manager is configured to have a maxThread-constraint of 50 threads.

Does it mean that each of the 4 managed servers is running at maximum 50 threads regarding requests dispatched to this work manager?  Or does it mean that all the managed servers together are supposed to have 50 threads at maximum?

Thanks,
Hadi

Answer (score 0):

it means that each of the 4 managed servers is running at maximum 50 threads.

Comment: This is also my understanding.  Unfortunately, I am experiencing the opposite behaviour.  I see that the 50 Threads are being distributed across all managed servers.  Is it immaginable that this behaviour is due to the F5-LoadBalancer?

Comment: Is it possible, that in a clustered environment, only one instance of the custom work manager is created, which causes that all the 4 managed servers are sharing this work manager(thread-pool)?

Comment: No it is not possible. You may need to increase your test load to see thread pools increasing in each server till 50.